# Importing Events

Tags: civievent, import

Is it possible to import Events? And if so, where do I start? I've not done anything more advanced than use the CiviCRM UI for imports before now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the extension [API csv Import GUI](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) .

Comment: Brill, thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import event participants, create the event as normal, then go to `Events > Import Participants`.  Note that your participants already need to exist as contacts.

If you want to import the event itself ... that's more complicated!

Comment: That's what I thought. Unfortunately it's the events themselves I'm looking to import.